# how many parameters can be in a function overloading?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
    basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&
    operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT* __s);
```

This is a function overloading for operator ***>>***. My question is why this function overloading could have two parameters?
usually, we write:

```
mystringStream >> myChar;
```

But this function has another variable ***__in***. How could I understand this?

Thanks!

Comment: See the "Bitshift Operators (used for Stream I/O)" section in the duplicate question for a complete explanation.

Comment: You don't have to, but since there are no answers, and your question is addressed by the duplicate, you can delete the question.